# "The process cannot access the file 'Default.rd.xml' because it is being used by another process." on AppVeyor CI

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, appveyor, cordova-windows

I am doing some work on `cordova-windows` (https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows), which is using AppVeyor for testing on Windows. One of the things that was missing, were tests with Visual Studio 2017 (only VS2015 was used to test before). So I added those and it works like a charm - mostly.

Unfortunately we now have a very strange test failure:
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ApacheSoftwareFoundation/cordova-windows/build/1.0.458

```
Started
Creating Cordova Windows Project:
    Path: testcreate 応用
    Namespace: com.test.app
    Name: 応用
Windows project created with cordova-windows@5.1.0-dev
Building project: C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate 応用\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
    Configuration : release
    Platform      : x64
  Patching 10 in prebuild event...
  Injected base.js reference to the www/index.html
  Removing /( *)(<script\s+(?:type="text\/javascript"\s+)?src="\/\/Microsoft.WinJS.2.0\/js\/base.js">\s*<\/script>)(\s*)/ from www/index.html
  Removing /( *)(<script\s+(?:type="text\/javascript"\s+)?src="\/\/Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1\/js\/base.js">\s*<\/script>)(\s*)/ from www/index.html
  CordovaApp.Windows10 -> C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate ??\build\windows\release\x64\win10\CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.0.0_x64.appx
  CordovaApp.Windows10 -> C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate ??\build\windows\release\x64\win10\Upload\CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.0.0_x64.appx
  CordovaApp.Windows10 -> C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate ??\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.0.0_Test\CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.0.0_x64.appxbundle
  CordovaApp.Windows10 -> C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate ??\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.0.0\CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.0.0_x64.appxbundle
  CordovaApp.Windows10 -> C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate ??\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_1.0.0.0_x64_bundle.appxupload
  Your package has been successfully created.
Building project: C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate 応用\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
    Configuration : release
    Platform      : x86
  Patching 10 in prebuild event...
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2975,5): error MSB3231: Unable to remove directory "build\windows\bld\PackageUploadLayout\". The process cannot access the file 'Default.rd.xml' because it is being used by another process. [C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate ??\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate 応用\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:155
                throw e;
                ^
Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate 応用\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
```

The relevant part is this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2975,5): error MSB3231: Unable to remove directory "build\windows\bld\PackageUploadLayout\". The process cannot access the file 'Default.rd.xml' because it is being used by another process. [C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate ??\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
```

This is not happening when I run the tests locally, meaning I can in no way reproduce what is going on here.

Any idea what process could block this `Default.rd.xml` file or `build\windows\bld\PackageUploadLayout\`?
How can I find out in a CI environment like AppVeyor?

---

Update:

Investigated a bit more by adding `/clp:Verbosity=normal` to the `msbuild` calls that are executed.

It runs a similar `msbuild` call 3 times (once per architecture). The first one succeeds, but during the second one the failure occurs. Makes sense as in the first iteration the folder doesn't exist yet, which it confirms with this output: `Directory "build\windows\bld\PackageUploadLayout\" doesn't exist. Skipping.`.

The last output before the failure then is `Removing directory "build\windows\bld\PackageUploadLayout\".` which matches what we get in the error message. No indicator *why* the removing doesn't work though.

Super strange: With `/clp:Verbosity=detailed` added to the `msbuild` call, the build actually succeeds! My guess: Because the output takes time, whatever is having a lock on the folder or file releases it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer, but rather investigation report. It is just not enough room comments to describe it. Here is what I did:

- forked your repo
- created AppVeyor project
- added [RDP](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/)
- connected with RDP
- installed [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)
- added filter to monitor objects which `path` ends with `bld\PackageUploadLayout\Properties\Default.rd.xml`
- run `npm test` manually from CMD

When the same error happened I see this:
[image]

I am not sure I understand why msbuild failed this way. I opened `SHARING VIOLATION` event, switched to process and see this:

[image]

What catches my eye is that `msbuild` version is 14. Should be 15 on `Visual Studio 2017 image`. We have version 14 installed for specific scenarios but default one is 15 (run `where msbuild` and you will see `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`). I am not sure where this path is set in your scripts, but I feel if you make it run correct `msbuild` version this may help.

Comment: Thank you _so_ much. The MSBuild selection code is indeed pretty wonky right now, evolved from VS13 to 15 and now also 17... But I have an idea how to tackle this now!

Comment: Unfortunately same problem with MSBuild 15.0 (from VS17) [+ new test unrelated failures...]: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3212,5): error MSB3231: Unable to remove directory "build\windows\bld\PackageUploadLayout\". The process cannot access the file 'Default.rd.xml' because it is being used by another process. [C:\projects\cordova-windows\testcreate ??\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]` https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Humbedooh/cordova-windows/build/1.0.890/job/gkbvd7l698uhi8ah

Comment: Is there any way you can run `handle.exe` against this file right before error occurs? It can show more about file usage or even fix the problem in weird way. Check this post: http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/5975-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process#comment_41824790

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is a `msbuild` call that builds a `.jsproj` - both the folder and file are never touched before or after, it's all during this build :/

Comment: example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild [ 'C:\\projects\\cordova-windows-adhdo\\testcreate 応用\\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj',
  '/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal',
  '/nologo',
  '/p:Configuration=release',
  '/p:Platform=x86',
  '/p:CordovaBundlePlatforms=x86',
  '/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload' ] { stdio: 'inherit' }`

Comment: Posted an update to my question with some more information. Unfortunately no hot lead :/

Comment: Can you try to make this sick test first in the order?

Comment: Did so, no change: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/janpio/cordova-windows-adhdo/build/1.0.30/job/f4rooonaeuplsldg (fails as first and last test).  
Or did you suggest to change the order of the 3 `msbuild` calls from my Update? (Problem is that one "build" that is being tested runs `msbuild` 3 times internally - but maybe I can find a workaround.)